# how to add pagination on fetch data react native

Tags: react-native, pagination

I am creating mobile app in react-native. I am fetching data from url and post to the product page using Actions.product(responseJson);
code to fetch data on home page:-

```
 handlePressProduct(id) {
    var url =
        "http://www.furnitureinfashion.net/menu_category_listing.php?cat_id=";
    fetch(url + id, {
        method: "GET"
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            Actions.product({ data: responseJson });
        });
}
```

on prodcut page i am getting data like this:-

```
  <View style={productStyle.products}>
            {this.props.data.map(dataImage => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.handlePressProduct.bind(
                        this,
                        dataImage["cPath"]
                    )}
                >
                    <View
                        key={dataImage["CategoryId"]}
                        style={productStyle.homeimg1}
                    >
                        <Image
                            source={{ uri: uri + dataImage["Image"] }}
                            style={{ width: 130, height: 130 }}
                        />
                        <Text style={productStyle.title}>
                            {" "}
                            {dataImage["Name"]}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={productStyle.shopbutton}>
                            SHOP NOW
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
        </View>
```

data i am fetching is too large. i want to add pagination in it. how can i add pagination ?

Comment: You may use `FlatList`

Comment: okay , can you please give me any example code

Comment: actually, i have checked FlatList earlier but not succeeded. can you please provide me code related to my functionality

Comment: Check this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pagination

Comment: Using FlatList can do this for you. You need slice your data and render them base on your page you loaded.

Example: https://github.com/trangcongthanh/react-native-news/blob/master/src/screens/NewsFeed/components/NewsFeed.js

Comment: any other idea ?

Comment: actually, i can't understand both of the example

Comment: @AhsanAli I have checked it with FlatList but its not working.  I can't understand let MockPersonList and also don't know where to assign my data this.props.data

Comment: @ThanhTrang I tried this but not working

Comment: In my example, I calculate the maxPage of response data if each page have 5 items. And every time `onEndReached` fired, I increase the current page in state by 1. Then, I slice the data from item `0` to item `currentPage * 5`.
This loop will end when currentPage > maxPage.

Comment: FYI about onEndReached: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onendreached

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pagination in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452707/pagination-in-react-native)